# How to provide an Azure Storage CNAME as part of the connection string?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

All the connection strings for an Azure Storage account seem to only be the original url + account.

Is there any way to change the connection string to an Azure Storage account to be my CNAME instead?

EDIT: The answer below is awesome and a few hours AFTER the answer was posted (and ticked) I found [some official documentation on this/the same answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json#create-a-connection-string-for-an-explicit-storage-endpoint) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great Question! I think you can but it will only work with `Blob Storage` as you can only specify a CNAME mapping for blob endpoint plus you will need to use your account name somewhere as it is used for authorization header computation. This is how I did it:

```
    static void ConnectViaCname()
    {
        var cred = new StorageCredentials("account-name", "account-key");
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(cred, new Uri("https://cnamemapping.com"), null, null, null);
        var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var containers = client.ListContainers();
        foreach (var container in containers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(container.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

If you wish to use connection string, please specify the connection string in this format:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;
BlobEndpoint=https://cnamemapping.com;
AccountName=account-name;
AccountKey=account-key
```

So the code would be:

```
    static void ConnectViaCname()
    {
        var connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;BlobEndpoint=https://cnamemapping.com;AccountName=account-name;AccountKey=account-key";
        var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
        var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var containers = client.ListContainers();
        foreach (var container in containers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(container.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well blow me down with a feather! That works!! You sir, are awesome. Side Note: `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https` :) :) always secure, please!

Comment: Regarding `https`, completely agree. It's just that I had a really old account with CNAME mapping done when https was not supported. That's why I used http to make sure things work. I will edit my question and change it to https.

Comment: Heads up @gauravmantri - the official docs also mention this! I just found it :P  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json#create-a-connection-string-for-an-explicit-storage-endpoint

Comment: :). Is this about HTTPS? For some reason I thought it is now supported (but I may be wrong).

Comment: Nope. this was about how the official docs actually mention your answer exactly. Meaning, I should have checked there first. (well, I did ... i just missed that section as I skimmed over that page and was reading another page about Storage CNames which didn't mention this at all).

Comment: Aah...I see. I also went to that page and read halfway through only :).